# Isolating the topk routine of dask

Tags: dask

I try to isolate the topk routine from dask.
Somehow it dies in isolation.

Apparently, numpy array instead of dask array is passed to the x argument during the recursion.

The original source code for topk is at: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/routines.py

Test program:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask.base import tokenize
from operator import getitem
import dask.sharedict as sharedict
from dask.array.core import Array

def topk(k, x):
    if x.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError("Topk only works on arrays of one dimension")

    token = tokenize(k, x)
    name = 'chunk.topk-' + token
    dsk = {(name, i): (topk, k, key)
           for i, key in enumerate(x.__dask_keys__())}
    name2 = 'topk-' + token
    dsk[(name2, 0)] = (getitem, (np.sort, (np.concatenate, list(dsk))),
                       slice(-1, -k - 1, -1))
    chunks = ((k,),)

    return Array(sharedict.merge((name2, dsk), x.dask), name2, chunks, dtype=x.dtype)

def main():
    x = np.arange(12)*8
    y = da.from_array(x, 7)
    print(y.topk(2).compute())
    print(topk(2, y).compute())

main()
```

Error:

```
  File "test_dask_argtopk.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_dask_argtopk.py", line 38, in main
    print(topk(2, y).compute())
  File "test_dask_argtopk.py", line 27, in topk
    for i, key in enumerate(x.__dask_keys__())}
AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute '__dask_keys__'
```

Comment: Your example above fails because you're using code you copied from the master branch with an older dask install. Some of the non-public methods were renamed in the last few weeks. Your code above works if you install dask from master.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense now. let me try.

Comment: nope. i installed master branch and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't accurately extract the code. Instead of commenting in too places, I'm just going to keep responding on the corresponding github issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2859. Please see my response there.